# How do I strip whitespace in a password field in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms-authentication

I have a login form in Bootstrap without any additional JavaScript (currently). I notice that quite a few users copy/paste the password from their signup mail and then somehow copy an additional space.

Therefore - the service doesn't allow them to login.

Now, I can of course strip the whitespace from the $_POST['password'] value and then the login would work. But the problem that remains is that the browser still stores the password INCLUDING the whitespace.

Is this something I should be concerned about and if so - how do I fix that?

Comment: Giving the user a good user experience is important, so if possible why not, check my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove whitespaces using JS `string.trim` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)) or jQuery `$.trim()` ([jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)) method.

In my opinion, it is bad practice to have a (copy-pasted) whitespace at the end of a password / username prevent the user from logging in. There are several discussions about that on [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=whitespace+password).

Comment: Thanks - UX offers an excellent question about this at http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75686/why-do-some-websites-including-google-trim-whitespaces-in-passwords

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this on the client side:

```
$('#txtPassword').on('blur', function() {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
});
```

This assumes your password textbox(input) has the id "txtPassword", you could change it to a different JQuery selector so it implements this functionality on all fields (username too maybe)

Comment: I would try using that code in `blur` event, otherwise it might strip whitespaces in the middle of the password.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off autocomplete on the password field.

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

In my opinion, it isn't your fault if the user remembers an incorrect password.

Comment: But imho it is bad user experience to have a (copy-pasted) whitespace and the end of a password / username prevent a user from logging in (there are several discussions regarding that point on ux.stackoverflow.com (http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=whitespace+password)

Comment: Turning off auto complete won't stop them from logging in with a white space at the end... It will stop the browser from remembering the password. There are **many** top level sites that will count it as an invalid password, because it is. A space is valid in today's passwords. "This is my password " is a perfectly valid password.